# How to Ctrl+Shift+←/→ to select previous or next word at the VSCode integrated terminal?

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code, shortcut, key-bindings

How to enable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> to select (highlight) previous or next word at the integrated terminal of VSCode?

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> in order to move the cursor by one word works perfectly, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> outputs D's and C's.

I tried these to the keybindings.json (same for right):

```json
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+left",
        "command": "-cursorWordStartLeftSelect",
        "when": "textInputFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+left",
        "command": "-workbench.action.terminal.resizePaneLeft",
        "when": "terminalFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+left",
        "command": "cursorWordStartLeftSelect",
        "when": "textInputFocus || terminalFocus"
    },
```

and

```json
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+left",
        "command": "-workbench.action.terminal.resizePaneLeft",
        "when": "terminalFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+left",
        "command": "cursorWordStartLeftSelect",
        "when": "terminalFocus"
    },
```

but didn't work. Any suggestions?

VSCode version: 1.40.2 x64
os: Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I've been plagued by the "C" and "D" output in my terminal as well. The keybinding used to work for me (for switching next/previous terminals), but then all of a sudden stopped. And I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found any relative option at VSCode. You 're better off using something like [oh-my-bash](https://github.com/ohmybash/oh-my-bash) or [ohmyzsh](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh) and I think that the integrated terminal of VSCode will pick up the configuration.

Comment: Take a look at this solution: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/345574/287494